# Is there an application that does two way sync of Magento and a billing software?

Tags: php, magento, crm, billing

I'm looking for an application for billing and inventory that could sync two-way with Magento. We run a online + offline store with the same set of inventory, and such a solution will make things a lot easier for us.

Any clues?

Comment: two way sync done properly is a tricky task (like using microsoft sync framework) i've done this on top of 1.3 series and conclusion is that doing it through php is just too resource hungry (comparing the object state) and doing it with other languages means a bit of reverse engineering the magento database structure and all the necessary actions to register an object . So i suggest you to think that if "sync" is really needed or is export/import enough to handle your tasks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The guys at Fontis have produced a 2 way sync between [MYOB and Magento](http://www.fontis.com.au/fontis-m2m-sync).  I haven't used it, but their code for other Magento extensions is great.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen a module that integrates with Sage somewhere out there on the web.  I had to custom build and export for my setup the dumped everything to Take Stock.  I guess the real question is: what financial software are you using internally.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the services of [SBOeConnect](http://www.sboeconnect.com/), which integrates with SAP Business One (this is at the time when I was associated with it about 3 months ago). I will not be able to comment on its current status but you may get benefited, as the service providers also do customizations, which I am also somewhat aware of.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Magento has a [data sync service](http://www.magentocommerce.com/product/bridgeconnect) you can check out, and I expect that your backend/ERP system may have a dedicated bridge as well. If not, you can use the Webservices built into Magento to build a sync'd system.

Make sure to choose a single system of record for your inventory information and have the other system feed from it for information.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe